# Mapping to Flow and using it as a List<Item>

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-flow

Im using retrofit and fetching data from news api.
I wanted to use flows so I do this in repository:

```
  fun getTopArticles(): Flow<List<Article>> {
        return flow {
            val topArticles = apiService.getTopHeadlinesArticles().articles
                .map { article ->
                    Article(
                        title = article.title,
                        content = article.content
                    )
                }
            emit(topArticles)
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
private val _observeTopArticles = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Article>())
    val observeTopArticles = _observeTopArticles.asStateFlow()

  init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            articleRepository.getTopArticles()
                .collect{
                    _observeTopArticles.value = it
                }
        }
    }
```

Activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch{
    viewModel.observeTopArticles.collect{
        if (it.isNotEmpty()){
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to get something like this:

```
[Article(I know something, some content)] etc.
```

But I get this:

```
[android.newz.domain.Article@5f612be, android.newz.domain.Article@700f1f]
```

I want to use it in RecyclerView.

Comment: BTW, why do you use a flow if you only return a single item in it? Do you plan to return multiple lists in the future? If not, then use a regular suspend function instead of a flow. Your code will be simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Currently im only returning 1 list but im using it since i need to search contents and titles of it. Not sure if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `Flow` code is fine. Looks like the problem is that `Article` doesn't have a `toString()` implementation, so you're just seeing the default String representation. Try making `Article` into a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html).

Comment: Omg i forgot data class Article, thank you <3